# SQL WHERE LIKE solo devuelve una fila y debería devolver más

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

La consulta

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE interests LIKE '%\"50\"%'"
```

Solo devuelve una fila, cuando debería devolver más. Este es el código:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE interests LIKE '%\"50\"%'");
$sql->execute();
$data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print_r($data);
```

Y esta es la respuesta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejecutando EXACTAMENTE la misma consulta en phpmyadmin devuelve los valores correctos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe lo que esta pasando aquí? Porque la consulta es exactamente igual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrige las comillas y optimiza la parte del **LIKE** ya que en tu código se nota un poco confuso. La siguiente linea de tu código:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE interests LIKE '%\"50\"%'");
```

Reemplazala por:

```
$parametro= 50;

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT 'id' FROM 'users' WHERE interests LIKE '%$parametro%');
```

**Nota:** Si **"50"** proviene de datos ingresados por el usuario (en vez de ser la constante 50 es una variable) recuerda utilizar **"bind"** para este tipo de **prepared statements**.

Además cambia tu instrucción **fetch()** por **fetchAll()** ya que **fetchAll()** te permitirá obtener en la salida más de un registro a diferencia de **fetch()** que sólo te permite obtener 1 registro por busqueda (aunque podrías combinarlo con un **bucle while o for** pero sería un poco redundante ya que para eso es que se creó **fetchAll**).

Dicho esto cambia la siguiente línea de tu código:

```
$data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Por:

```
$data = $sql->fetchAll();
```

Eso es todo, espero te sea de utilidad. Un Saludo

Comment: you're a genius bro

Comment: @QUIQUELHAPPY Gracias. Me alegra que fue de utilidad! Un saludo bro

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> PDOStatement::fetch — Obtiene la siguiente fila de un conjunto de
>   resultados

Por lo que tu instrucción solo devolverá el siguiente registro (el primero). Necesitas iterar para poder obtenerlos todos.